# Criteria of a manifold

Tags: geometry, manifolds, physics, mathematical-physics

I am self studying Frankel's The Geometry of Physics, early in the text he poses the example:

The x axis of the xy plane can be described as the locus of the quadratic $F(x,y) := y^2=0$. Both partial derivatives vanish on the locus, the x axis.

Is it correct to say that this is because the partial with respect to $x$ is $0$ always, while the partial with respect to $y$ is $0$ only along the $x$ axis (ie when $y=0$)

Also, what would be a manifold in this setting? Since all along the $x$ axis the partial with respect to $x$ is $0$, then the jacobian criteria is violated and it is not a manifold; however, the text says that the $x$ axis is a 1-manifold.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Yes to the first question. For the second, the set theoretic zero set is a manifold, as you say. So the Jacobian criterion isn't a necessary condition, when you are thinking just about sets. But interpreted with certain extra structure that remembers the equations, the zero set is not a manifold. Don't worry about this for now.

Comment: @AreaMan Thank you. When you are talking only about sets what are the necessary conditions?

Comment: Either the existence of charts (/coordinate patches), or the (local) existence of a set of functions cutting out the set and satisfying the Jacobian condition.